# Magento 2 What limit for create Attributes sets and Attributes Groups?

Tags: magento2, attributes, attribute-set

Is anyone there to tell me how many we can create Attribute sets?

How many can we create Attribute group?

Is any limit for this?

Comment: is there any limit you found in Magento v-1.x ?

Comment: @inrsaurabh no i did not check in magento 1 because in magento 1 i create only 8 attribute sets

Comment: because in one of the project i saw there are around 10 group and more than 100 custom attributes , i didn`t found any topic or related to this limitation , neither i think at database level that there will be any restrictions.

Comment: but i need confirm before because if i go for create 25 attributes sets after create attributes sets magento would not say to me that attributes set limit is x.....

Comment: Please tell us also how many we can create Attributes ?
Can we create Attribute approx. 220 ?

Comment: Please tell us know if someone got this answer... Because i am facing some problem with this indexing issue - Products are not showing on website. We have total 450 attributes... so flat temporary table is not created... getting below error 1118 Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535.